# Unable to ping vmware guest from another vmware guest

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, windows-networking

I would like to ping one vmware guest from another one. Both are Windows XP and use NAT. I set IP manually for VMnet8 to 192.168.18.1. (no using Obtain IP address automatically). Also I'm not able to ping neither guest1 nor guest2 from host.

I'm using VMWare Player 5.

Host machine (Windows 7):

```
    Ethernet adapter VMware Network Adapter VMnet8:

    Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
    Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::dc81:34e2:779d:595d%19
    IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.18.1
    Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
    Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
```

Guest 1:

```
    Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : localdomain
    IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.18.131
    Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
    Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.18.2
```

Guest 2:

```
    Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : localdomain
    IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.18.132
    Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
    Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.18.2
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 58):

I just ran into the exact same problem while configuring my server 2008 and windows 7 vm's in 
VMware workstation 9. what helped is disabling the firewall and running the following command at the windows command prompt

`netsh firewall set icmpsetting 8 enable`

at that point I was able to ping one VM then both once I performed the command on both. this differnce between our scenarios is I have my VM configured using Bridged connections

Comment: netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="ICMP Allow incoming V4 echo request" protocol=icmpv4:8,any dir=in action=allow   is the non-deprecated version on win10 and the firewall does not need to be disabled in this scenario.   https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/947709/how-to-use-the-netsh-advfirewall-firewall-context-instead-of-the-netsh

Comment: Or just Enable the "Inbound Rules" -> "File and Printer Sharing (Echo Request - ICMPv4-In)" in `wf.msc` on Windows

Answer (score 7):

I know it is an old question, but I had a similar trouble recently. On VMware Workstation 12.+ go to `Edit -> Virtual Network Editor...` Select a network used by the problematic VM and make sure that `"Connect a host virtual adapter to this network"` checkbox is set for this network. In my case, it was not. After it was set, the host was able to ping the guest and guests were able to talk to each other.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Turned out to be the root cause of an issue I was having. Three hours of my life I'm never getting back.

Answer (score 3):

You can ping ip from one virtual machine to another machine by using these steps:

1. Go to menu VM -> Setting -> select network adapter: NAT
2. Go to menu VM -> setting -> select options Tab and select

Guest Isolation : ENABLED, ENABLED and select box : ENABLE VMCI

Answer (score 2):

1. Make network setting as Bridged.
2. Enable VMCI (this enables hosts , guests to communicate with each other)

Answer (score 1):

If i am understanding your question. You now have both VMs on the same network segment VMnet8,

1. Enable file and print sharing from the firewall settings on both VMs
2. Ensure that from the host machine (Windows 7) that the network adapter for VMnet8 is enabled. Also open the network adapter to check if you are actually connecting to VMnet8 network address. Then try to ping both addresses.
3. If this still doesnt work, perform ipconfig/all from host machine and paste the output here so that i can see how the network address are distributed.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. Try installing VMware tools in guest operating system.
2. Check if firewall is enable
3. If 1 and 2 are ok, try using share internet connection

[image: Share internet]

After sharing connection the VMnet8 IP address will be changed to `192.168.137.1`, set up the IP `192.168.18.1` and try again

Answer (score 1):

1. Check the firewall on all the windows system. If it's enabled,
   disable it.
2. If you still are unable to ping, Open the virtual network editor and
       check if you are using the same VMnet adapter for both the VM's,
       this adapter should be present in the host machine's network
       adapters as well. Share a screenshot of what you are seeing in the
       virtual network editor.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to ping from VMs and the host by setting the VM's network settings to "Bridged" mode.  This, in short, places them all on the same physical network.  This coupled with your static IP addresses should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

In Menu bar

> select the Host-> Virtual Network Settings -> Host Virtual Network Mapping...

set your drop down list as your host Network Adapter...If You can not ping Check your Firewall Status Because the Firewall is blocked the 'ping' packets

Answer (score 0):

On both Operation Systems, must turnoff firewall.
I using MS SERVER 2012 R2 & MS WIN-7 as a client. First of all call "RUN BOX" window logo button+ R, once RUN box appeared type "firewall.cpl" at Window Firewall setting you will see "Turn Window Firewall On or Off" like this you click it & chose "turn off window firewall" on both Private and Public Setting then OK. Ping again on guests OS.
GOOD-LUCK 
Aungkokokhant

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add, that yes. While using the NAT adapter settings in Vmware and turning off windows firewall I was able to ping other guest machines in my test environment.

Sidenote: Best practice would be to implement a hardware firewall in larger environments and turn off windows firewall on the Domain Controller.

Answer (score 0):

There are several related solutions available on the internet, but it all depends on the configuration of the machine and the firewall rules.

For me below solution is worked:

- Disabled the VMware Network Adapter VMNet8
- Removed the network from the VM
- Enabled the VMware Network Adapter VMNet8
- Re-added the Network to VM, and set it to NAT
- Restarted the machine

Answer (score 0):

If the Guest OS is Windows follow below steps -

For Windows 10 -

Turn off the Firewall Protection Completely in the Windows Guest OS

- Open Windows Security App > Select Firewall & Network Protection > Turn off Firewall for Domain Network, Private Network & Public Network.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this issue by following the steps defined in [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1214547/unable-to-ping-from-vms-to-host-machine) post also.
If you have a firewall enabled in Windows, ping requests are blocked by default. I have virtual machine on VMWare configured as windows server with IP address manually assigned as 2.2.2.5.
Now to ping guest ip address 2.2.2.5 from my host machine I have to do two things only on `guest` machine

1. If you are in `workgroup` and not in `Domain` then Set your guest machine current Nework profile to `private`
2. `Turn off firewall` on `private network`(if on `workgroup`) on guest virtual machine
   `OR`
   Enable Inbound firewall rule for File and Printer Sharing (Echo Request - ICMPv4-In and ICMPv6-In. There are three rules one for each (public, private, domain environment so enable rule based on your environment)) /* This is recommended instead of turning firewall off on private network */

[image]

[image]

[image]
Now the ping 2.2.2.5 should work from host pc

Answer (score -1):

[image]

I came to the same problem and tried all methods on internet, and finally worked it out by accident. May you could try this(see in the picture)

Comment: altough the image might help, you should also describe the answer in a few words to make it more clear.

Comment: sorry, my first time to post on stackoverflow. I should describe in detail.

Comment: The os of my host pc is win10 while the virtual os is fedora 24. I use WiFi to connect to the router with DHCP service, therefore the host pc and the virtual pc have ip in the same network segment. But they could ping all other machines except for each other. And I had unchecked all the virtual network adapter in settings of vmware player, it still didn't work.

Comment: Finally in the properties of the bridge network(on my pc, it is an adapter created by vmware besides the WLAN adapter, right click it and then check the properties), I tried to uncheck the WLAN (as in the picture), and that worked! And now I check the properties again, I find the apps automatically check the "ethernet" item. Could someone explain that?