# Can ping IP but cannot ping hostname - intermittent problem

Tags: networking, windows-10, ping, hostname

I tried searching for my answer on google and then just stackoverflow but clearly I am not using the right keywords.

Problem: I have two windows 10 laptops on my LAN, both wireless connections (if that matters). And the "main" laptop seems to have forgotten the "spare" laptops name.  I could two days ago "ping SPARE" and it would work.  Today MAIN cannot ping (or tracert) SPARE.  And yes I did power down MAIN between the two sessions.

Addition clue: MAIN could not ping the IP of SPARE  - until I had SPARE Ping MAIN.  and THEN main knew how to ping the IP of spare

Does anyone out there recognize this situation? and can you help a programmer who's in over his head with networking details?

Thanks
Harry

Comment: Perhaps this would go better on [su]?

Comment: never posted there before. I suppose I could. thanks for the tip.

Comment: I came across this page [link]https://www.lifewire.com/fix-ipv6-no-network-access-error-4684594 where I found its Step #6 resolved my issues...Although I still need to give my computer the acid test of powering down and seeing if the correction holds.....

Answer (score 2):

When the computer can ping with the IP it means there is no connections errors between them , the problem is in the DNS server used by the comupters , DNS ( Domain Name System ) is the protocol used to translate the SPARE name to the PC's actual ip address .

Answer (score 1):

You can ping another PC using both

- host name and
- ipaddress.

If you can not ping using both then please see solution provided by me  on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12332850/unable-to-ping-vmware-guest-from-another-vmware-guest/72765975#72765975) link of stackoverflow.

[image]

However if you can ping using IP address but not by host name then there are other options to try  as well like

- create entry in host file (most common location of this file is C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts)
- execute command `ipconfig /flushdns`  and   `ipconfig /registerdns` on HP8 pc

Comment: thank you for the tip @Hemendr - I might be re-exploring this setup with a mix of windows 10 and 11 machines in the near future. This might help.